# Split one row to many in same database table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-sql-data-modeler

We have a requirement where we want to split one row to many rows ( in the same table ) based on some conditions.

Let's suppose we have this table :

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | V1 |
| 2 | V2 |
| 3 | V3 |

Requirement is,

- if ID=1, split this row into two more rows where IDs of new rows will be 4 and 5 and the value will be V1 (same as ID = 1 value) only.
- if ID=2, don't split.
- if ID=3, split this row into one more row where ID of the new row will be 6 and value will be V3 (same as ID = 3 value) only.

The final o/p will be :

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | V1 |
| 4 | V1 |
| 5 | V1 |
| 2 | V2 |
| 3 | V3 |
| 6 | V3 |

I am looking out for some SQL script/Stored Proc that will help me in achieving the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate the rows with a `join` and derived table . . . and then use `union all` to bring in the existing rows:

```
select id, value
from t
union all
select x.new_id, t.value
from t join
     (select 1 as old_id, 4 as new_id from dual union all
      select 1 as old_id, 5 as new_id from dual union all
      select 3 as old_id, 6 as new_id from dual 
     ) x
     on t.id = x.old_id;
```

If you just want to insert the values, use `insert` with the second query.

Answer (score 2):

You can join your table with numbers as follows:

```
select case when t.id = 2 then t.id
            when t.id = 3 then t.id * lvl
            when t.id = 1 and lvl > 1 then lvl+2 
            else lvl 
      end as id, t.value 
  from your_table t
  cross join (select level as lvl from dual connect by level <=3)
where t.id = 1 or (t.id=2 and lvl=1) or (t.id = 3 and lvl <= 2)
```